# Is the use of "hereby" superfluous?

Tags: word-usage

Is the use of "hereby" ever essential?  I get the feeling it is always superfluous.  "As a result of this document or utterance" seems to be trivially true.  For example:

> I hereby declare that what I am uttering has meaning.

Why would I utter something in an authoritative context if I don't intend for said utterance to have a result?  Why would I put instructions or a definition in a document if I did not *really* intend to define something?

Again:

> It is defined that to 'discard' a command is to [place that command in an omelet and surrender that omelet to the duck army].

Even if my new definition of 'discard' is totally out of sync with the normal meaning of 'discard', the sentence is still clear and has the same meaning as if I had written "it is *hereby* defined that...".

Even the example sentence given by Google confounds me:

> "the Port Authority hereby solicits proposals from developers"

If "hereby" was deleted from that sentence, would it really have a different meaning?  The Port Authority is clearly soliciting proposals about whatever gives that sentence context.  Maybe the Port Authority doesn't normally solicit proposals, but now it does now because it was written there, not because it was "hereby" written.

Comment: Yes and no; in the same way that in "With this ring, I thee wed", *with this ring* is "superfluous".

Comment: "Hereby" is a legalism; it refers to the current writing, or the current testimony, as the instrument by which the declaration is being made.

Comment: See also: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/170736/correct-use-of-hereby

Comment: Your final example sentence would have a different meaning if "hereby" was omitted. The usual, or at least more frequent, mechanism for soliciting proposals from developers would be a formal RFP (request for proposals) which details the request. Thus, many might go looking for that RFP if "hereby" was not included. Of course, it could be that whoever wrote the sentence didn't know what they were saying, and the RFP *is* available elsewhere.

Comment: @TimRomano I suppose it makes sense in a legal document to identify the instrument of declaration.  Am I right to say that in a legal setting all "facts" subject to dispute, so it needs to be clear where a fact came from?

Comment: @Mutant Platypus: Pretty much, though it's possible for the parties to stipulate certain facts which are not in dispute, in order to move things along.  Also, in trials the facts that matter are only those facts which have been admitted into evidence, and it's not uncommon for facts to be barred from evidence as if they did not exist. Juries can be instructed to ignore a fact which has been presented to them, even if its truth is not in doubt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was interested to discover that the voluminous, unabridged *Black's Law Dictionary* (1968) doesn't have an entry for *hereby*. The reason for the omission, evidently, is that—contrary to popular belief—*hereby* has no special legal meaning.

It follows that the use of *hereby* in legal and quasi-legal notices means nothing more nor less than what a general dictionary says it means. Here is the brief entry for the word in *Merriam-Webster's Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary* (2003):

> **hereby** *adv* (13c): by this means

A notice published in a local newspaper announcing one's candidacy for public office might be worded like this one, from the [*[Kingstree, South Carolina] County Record*](http://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/lccn/sn93067841/1920-08-26/ed-1/seq-13/#date1=1836&index=1&rows=20&words=hereby&searchType=basic&sequence=0&state=&date2=1922&proxtext=hereby&y=16&x=12&dateFilterType=yearRange&page=1) (August 26, 1920):

> **For Congress.** I hereby announce myself a candidate for re=election to Congress from the Sixth Congressional District, subject to the rules of the Democratic Primary. PHILIP J. STOLL.

Or like any of the other 51 such announcements on the same page of that newspaper, along with one iconoclastic announcement to the contrary:

> **Not a Candidate** I hereby announce to my friends and the public that I have decided to withdraw my name as candidate for Cotton Weigher at Kingstree. W. R. BROWN.

In all of these instances, "hereby" means something like "by publishing this announcement in this newspaper." You might argue that the reader, being uniquely well situated to observe that the announcement is indeed in the particular newspaper in front of him or her, doesn't need to be told more than "I announce myself a candidate..." But I think it is inaccurate to infer that the "hereby" is therefore superfluous. Interpreted literally, the notifications indicate that each such candidacy had not, until announced in the newspaper, been announced publicly at all. So at least on its face, "hereby" conveys the information "by this means **and by no other**."

Answer (score 1):

Some words do not add meaning, exactly, but are nevertheless not superfluous.  This happens when the word is present to add a certain feeling to a construction.  Most often, I suspect, it's to soften an expression.  For example,

> 1. Have you seen my pack of chewing gum, by any chance?
> 2. Have you seen my pack of chewing gum?

We might use (1) instead of (2) when we want to make sure we don't want to risk that the other person think this is more of an accusation than an honest question.

Another point is that "I declare" might be understood to affirm or state something emphatically.  Sticking "hereby" in there prevents the reader from potentially parsing things differently than is intended.